# Group By for Combobox Filter Sort

Tags: sql, ms-access, sorting, vba, combobox

I've created a basic Combobox Filter Sort that sorts through Company Regions for my company (Acronyns mostly) we refer to these as AOR's or Area of Reference. After defining your AOR, it limits the next combo box to show only Countries in that specific AOR, hense the Filter Sort. But, my problem is - when it displays the countries after selecting an AOR - It displays ALL RECORDS in that specific country, instead of just 1 country listing.

Basically, It isn't grouping my countries - and when I select "Totals" which normally gives me only unique results, this doesnt work.

My question, How can I re-write this code to include a Group By?

My Code:

```
Private Sub cboRegion_AfterUpdate()
  ' Region -> Country
  Dim sManagerSource As String
  sManagerSource = "SELECT [FullEmail].[AORID], [FullEmail].[ID], [FullEmail].[Country] " & _
                   "FROM FullEmail " & _
                   "WHERE [AORID] = " & Me.cboRegion.Value
  Me.cboCountry.RowSource = sManagerSource
  Me.cboCountry.Requery
End Sub
```

My SQL statement looks like this (It's got Group By in it, but it doesn't GROUP)

```
SELECT FullEmail.AORID, FullEmail.ID, FullEmail.Country
FROM FullEmail
GROUP BY FullEmail.AORID, FullEmail.ID, FullEmail.Country
HAVING (((FullEmail.AORID)=1));
```

Thanks in advance for reading through!

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer is correct, except with a having clause you need to use aggregates... so just use where.

```
SELECT Country
FROM FullEmail
WHERE AORID=1
GROUP BY Country;
```

That should fix you up. When you use HAVING it looks at what you've selected, since you didn't select AORID, it didn't know what to do.

Comment: I've inputed this as my SQL statement and nothing has changed. Perhaps I'm missing something in my explanation or maybe I've explained my issue improperly?

Comment: Did you maybe forget to replace WHERE AORID=1 with "AORID=" & Me.cboRegion.Value?

Comment: It is also possible that the data isn't being recorded exactly the same each time... try saying SELECT Trim(Country) and GROUP BY Trim(Country)

Comment: When I input what you said I get this:

SELECT FullEmail.Country
FROM FullEmail
WHERE ((("AORID=" & [Me].[cboRegion].[Value])<>False))
GROUP BY FullEmail.Country;

Any idea?

Comment: You can't put conditions in there like that. Try something like this: "SELECT FullEmail.Country FROM FullEmail WHERE (((AORID=" & Me.cboRegion.Value & "))) GROUP BY FulLEmail.Country;" That should do it

Comment: Still no luck with that @misterManager - Sorry about this, I really appriciate your help. Not sure why it's not working.

Comment: I think its because I have this in "AfterUpdate" - is that a possibility? I don't understand the reason why - But I think its due to my Main ID Field, it constantly gets refreshed whenever the value in the first combobox changes, so my filtered items in the 2nd combo are reset to showing there ID value.

Comment: @Colin let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2626/discussion-between-mistermanager-and-colin)